# Check if form is filled before submitting

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, textbox, submit-button

I have a form called choose_dates.php that submits to a file called process.php. The form consists of a textbox, a dropdown list and a submit button. I have set it up so that you can submit either one value, or the other, or both at the same time. **I would like to have it such that if the user has put a value in the textbox AND the dropdown list, then a prompt will ask if that is what he/she really wants to do. The code below doesn't seem to do that when the submit button is pressed.** The rest of my code (that I have not placed on here) works fine, this is more of a user interface issue.

```
<form name="dates" action="process.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="submitDate">
<select name="removeException">
<option value="some-value">display dropdown stuff</option>
.
.
</select>
     <input type="submit" value="submit" 
        <?php
        if($_POST['submitDate'] != "" and $_POST['removeException'] != "")
        {
        echo " onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit both values at the same time?')\" ";
        }
        ?>
        tabindex="2">   
</form>
```

And of course, please ask any questions if what I said isn't clear enough. Regards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to do that on the client side using javascript ( preferably ). The post data will be submitted when the form is submitted. Try adding this function as your form's onsubmit event

```
function func(){
    var a = document.getElementsByName('removeException'),
        b = document.getElementsByName('submitDate');
    if(a[0].value!=null && b[0].value!=null){
        var c = confirm('Are you sure you want to submit both values at the same time?')
        if(c){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
<form name="dates" action="process.php" method="POST" onSubmit='return func()'>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. Do I need to place the script above or inside the form?

Comment: nevermind, I forgot a curly brace. A dialog box does show up! however, when I click cancel, the form still gets submitted. AND the dialog box still shows up even if just one field is entered.

Comment: Nothing seemed to change in terms of how it behaved, the form is still submitting even when the cancel button is hit, and the dialog shows up when only one field is filled out. :(

Comment: @dmkumar That's odd, shouldn't be behaving that way, as you can see, the script I wrote should do exactly what you demand. It's possible that your select tag's initial (empty) option's value is different than null, in which case instead of null you should fill your default value in the expression

Comment: Silly mistake, I had the script above all my content, and I moved it below where the buttons get defined and it works fine for the most part. Now the only problem is that when the cancel button is hit, the form still gets submitted. I also did what you said about changing null to "". I have edited the code you provided to make it look like what I have. btw thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @dmkumar The way the code is provided in the answer should return false, in other words cancel the submit, if the value of c is null. Null values are accepted to be 0, '0', '', null, false and correct me if I'm missing some. Anyway, if you press cancel then the value of c should become null which would cause the script to return false. I guess you can change `onSubmit` to the following `onSubmit='return func()'`

Comment: WOOOO!!! that did it!!! Thanks for you're help, also I would like to note that I changed `onsubmit` to `onclick` and I moved this to the submit button declaration rather than in the form declaration. I'll add my code to your answer so everyone can see. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Always happy to help, but you should not do that. Keep the code in the onsubmit event because there can be multiple submit buttons and it's not correct to have a submit handler on a button, technically. Good luck! :P

Answer (score 0):

Add onsumbit="return checks();" in form tag.
checks is a Javascript function that verify everything is good, if not, return false and the form will not be submited. If true, the form will be submited normally. just move your onclick to onsumbit in form.

Comment: could you perhaps elaborate a bit more? can you use the 'checks()' function in context of what I have? I don't really understand how it is supposed to work.